# How to take screenshot in headless mode in test framework with protractor/cucumber/typescript

Tags: protractor, cucumber, headless-browser, takesscreenshot

I want to execute my test cases on headless mode and capture screenshots on failure.

I have included the below lines of code to run in the headless mode.

```
chromeOptions: {args: [ 'no-sandbox',"--headless", "--disable-gpu",  "--window-size=800,600" ]},
```

This executes the test cases in the headless mode without issues. But on failure, it attaches white blank screenshot with the below code.

```
const screenshot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
scenario.attach(new Buffer(screenshot, 'base64'), "image/png");
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the similar issue, below could be a problem which causing this issue-

I have used the below code to run in the headless mode

```
chromeOptions: {args: [ 'no-sandbox',"--headless", "--disable-gpu",  "--window-size=800,600" ]},
```

After that, I had added code to maximize the screen due to which a blank image was taken as screenshot. I commented that code and executed and it worked fine!!!